# Router blocking Facebook

Tags: router, blacklist

I'm trying to find out a way to block the ability to do in-app payments through Facebook from our router but I have no idea on what I need to block.

Blocking app.facebook.com blocks all access to Facebook apps, which I don't want to do. I only want to block the ability to purchase in-game content in Facebook apps.

Comment: You might be better off asking in https://money.stackexchange.com/ (topic primarily about personal finances) or https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ (interpersonal relationship). Using technology is one thing, but you might want to approach this differently.

Comment: If the money is yours (eg. "money that we don't have"), then you can and should be asking over on those other sites. You should also talk with your bank, and perhaps with adult services in your area. A good interpersonal skill is boundaries, which, in this situation, means the systems and habits by which you protect yourself from harm caused by your mother's lack of self control.

Comment: There is no way you are going to block Facebook in-app payments, at least not with a consumer grade router... There isn't one or single range of IP's or URL's used for processing payments and developers can use multiple ways to process payments. A high-end enterprise grade router, such as Meraki or Watchguard for example, may be able to block some of this traffic without blocking Facebook in general, but the cost of the router would likely exceed making the payments.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it router-side, but I'm pretty sure there's a way to do it client side with some parental-control software or whatever. She will most likely notice that somehow though. What I would suggest instead is to talk to the bank. They are very well able to block specific types of payments. However, she will notice that too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cut this off closer to the source. Cancel her credit cards.

Comment: I'm unable to do this. She still needs her cards for food and to pay bills. I just need to find a way to only stop facebook payments. I'm also trying to do this behind the scenes as she doesnt know that I know.

Comment: If this is a minor, execute your parental rights and do what is necessary to get the spending under control... If this is a person of legal age, take appropriate action, since it seems sitting down and coming to an adult agreement is not one of your options (although, it's the one I would recommend).